# Rails 4 validation not working

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model which I would like to validate the name if it is part of an array that I get from somebody else's API.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :exists_at_api?

  def exists_at_api?
    api_data.detect { |d| d == self.name }
  end
end
```

The problem occurs when I send invalid data

The validation gets called, and returns `false`, but the model is still saved.

I also tried this variation of the above with the same results:

```
validate :name, if: :exists_at_api?
```

I'm sure this is something simple, can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add something to the `errors` hash to indicate the failure.  See [the Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators) for details and examples.

Try something like:

```
validate :exists_at_api?

def exists_at_api?
  if api_data.detect { |d| d == self.name }
    errors.add(:name, "can't be whatever...")
  end
end
```

Comment: Should be `unless api_data.detect{ |d| d==self.name}`

Comment: I got it working, I'll accept the answer as soon as it lets me